# How to add a bindingSource

Tags: vb.net

```
Public Sub refereshcmb(ByVal selectQ As String, ByRef cmb As ComboBox, ByVal display As String, ByVal value As String)
            dataAdap = New SqlDataAdapter(selectQ, Connection)
            Dim dt As New DataTable
            dataAdap.Fill(dt)
            cmb.DataSource = dt
            cmb.DisplayMember = display
            cmb.ValueMember = value
        End Sub
```

i dont want to call this function in each form everytime i m adding new values to combo box. can anyone help with the binding source method

Comment: How do you add values to combo box?

Comment: thats not the point.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you expect to gain by using a `BindingSource`.  I do recommend using them but that's not going to reduce your code at all.  It just means that you have to bind the `DataTable` to the `BindingSource` and that to the `ComboBox` instead of the `DataTable` direct to the `ComboBox`.  It will actually be one more line of code.  What do you think is going to happen?

Comment: i m using form.show() instead of form.showDialog() . it means every form will load once during the entire session. when switching the forms i want to referesh the comboboxes ( for example the comboboxes are in frmMain ) and when i m adding new values to comboboxes in different forms and while returning to frmMain i want the frmMain to call its Load event (i have tried the me.referesh() but its not working ) - @jmcilhinney

Comment: You don't call events.  Events are raised.  Presumably you mean that you want the form's `Load` event handler, which is the method that handles the `Load` event, to be called.  Why?  What you actually need is for some particular code to be executed.  Why try to force the `Load` event handler to be executed in order to do that?  Why not actually put the code somewhere that it will be executed every time that form gets focus, like the `Activated` event handler?

Comment: i guess thats what i have been looking for .... could u plz tell how to use the activated event handler?

Comment: @jmcilhinney can u help ?

Comment: You handle the form's `Activated` event the same way you handle any other event.  Use the Properties window after having clicked the Events button at the top or else use the drop-down lists at the top of the code window.  Once you have an event handler, simply add the code for whatever it is you want to do.  If you want to retrieve data from a database, write code to do that.